Orbeon Forms: Triggering an Auto Form Save
We have a situation whereby the user is losing form data when they navigate away from the form (e.g. clicking on a URL link).
So we want to force a form SAVE before the URL is opened.
Is there a way to auto-trigger a form SAVE?
Many thanks in advance.
PeteA

By the time the browser starts navigating away from the page, there's little that can be done reliably, as the page might be "killed" at any time. However, there are a couple of techniques that can be used to mitigate this risk:

Using autosave, which regularly saves any changes the user has made in the background.
Warning the user when data is unsafe, which is enabled by default but can be disabled through a property setting.

If the navigation is triggered by a button you added with Form Builder to the form being clicked on by users, then you can implement the navigation by adding the following to your form definition, just inside the xf:model, here assuming that your button is named navigate-button.
<xf:action event="DOMActivate" observer="navigate-button-control">
    <xf:load resource="https://www.orbeon.com/" xxf:show-progress="false"/>
</xf:action>

This gives:

If you prefer to save before navigating, you use:
<xf:action event="DOMActivate" observer="navigate-button-control" type="xpath">
    fr:run-process(
        'oxf.fr.detail.process', 
        'save then navigate(uri = "https://www.orbeon.com/")'
    )
</xf:action>


Hi Alex,
We have already created a warning scenario, but this isn't the best user experience
Ideally we would want to to the following  once the URL has been clicked (possibly via an action):

Trigger a save of the form data
Possibly a delay for the save to occur
Open the URL

PeteA

Alex,
FYI - the two links above will not open..

@PeteAtkin Those links should work now. We changed our registrar, so some of the pages were temporarily down on Thursday and Friday. But please let me know if some of those links still don't work.

@PeteAtkin Where is the URL that users click on? Is it inside or outside the form? Any chance you could share a screenshot of what the situation looks like?

I'll knock-up a quick form on the Orbeon demo site tomorrow..

Here is a mock-up form which uses the workaround you mention above:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/af924c90fae4231652d5cc8b23452c6e4c467c87?form-version=1
However, we would like to display the Google URL immediately, and when the user clicks on the URL, then an auto-save is performed before the URL is opened. It could be done via a button too..

@PeteAtkin To clarify, are you suggesting that when users click on the button, if there is unsaved data, they would be prompted before navigating away from the page? Alternatively, are you suggesting that when users click on the button, the data should always be saved before navigating to the target page?

The latter..
When the user clicks on the button, then an auto-save is triggered before navigating to the URL.
PeteA

@PeteAtkin Got it. I've updated my answer above. You'll let me know if this works for you.

@PeteAtkin Have you had a chance to try the XForms mentioned in my updated response above? If so, is it what you were looking for?

I will try the solution provided above tomorrow morning

I tried you answer above Alex, but it doesn't appear to work (see https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/af924c90fae4231652d5cc8b23452c6e4c467c87).
Any suggestions??
PeteA

@PeteAtkin I updated your example, and it now works for me. The xf:action really needs to be exactly as mentioned in my answer above; most notably, you had a type="javascript" that was causing a problem. I also moved the xf:action to the top of the source to make it easier to edit with Edit Source. Let me know if this works for you as well. -Alex

I cant get it to work in either Chrome or Edge.
And we would really like an "auto-save", not a popup reminder if at all possible...

@PeteAtkin Have you tried going to https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/PJA_TEST/PJA_TEST_016/new?form-version=1, entering something in the First name field, and then clicking on the Open Google button? If I try this here with Chrome, I see the dialog showing as in the video attached to my response above. Regarding the autosave, it will happen automatically if the user is logged in, but only after a short delay, so you still want to have that warning popup in case the user navigates away before the autosave had a chance to happen.

The solution above dosent work in our Form Builder, but does work OK in Form Runner via the web browser.
However it does not work on the mobile device, so more investigation is required..

@PeteAtkin I am glad it is working for you in Form Runner. Regarding Form Builder, tracking whether the data is "clean" or "dirty" is only done when the form is in "new" or "edit" mode. It isn't tracked in "test" mode, so you won't get this alert when using the Test functionality in Form Builder. As for the mobile app, when you click on the link, does it open in Safari, or does it open in an embedded browser within the app you are using?

Hi Alex,
nfortunately it doesn't do anything on the mobile device, it simply navigates to the chosen URL.
PeteA

@PeteAtkin The way I envision it, when you're using a mobile app to fill out a form, clicking on the link opens the page in Safari. Unlike the scenario where the form is initially loaded in a browser, there's no loss when you click the link because you can easily return to the app where you were filling out the form. Does the actual interaction differ from my understanding here?

SAP are aware of this issue.
But in the mean time the workaround is the force a form save when clicking on a URL (via a button and action).
Is this scenario possible?
Note: ideally we do not want any popups..

@PeteAtkin Yes, it is; I've added the code to use to trigger a "save" before navigating to the URL.

Sorry for being a bit thick here..
But which code did you add?
PeteA

@PeteAtkin It is the last code block in my above answer, just after "If you prefer to save before navigating, you use:". It is running the XPath function fr:run-process(), passing a process which does save then navigate(uri = "https://www.orbeon.com/"). You'll let me know if this works for you. -Alex

@PeteAtkin Did you get a chance to try running the version in the last code block of my previous answer, the one using fr:run-process()?

Hi Alex - thanks for the code - that works perfectly..

@PeteAtkin Excellent! I am glad we sorted this out.
